# java.net.UnknownHostException when accessing through https

Tags: java, http, networking

I am getting `java.net.UnknownHostException` while executing this particular line of code:

```
int status = client.executeMethod(method);
```

where client is an `HttpClient` object.

Could someone get me solution, please?

I had searched for this problem and I got some comments related to network proxy server settings.

By the way I am able to access the server site throw a web browser.

Comment: Provide your implementation and the error you are getting.

Comment: Wild guess: your URL is missing a `:`. But without the actual source code, **including the URL** and all the steps before the `executeMethod` part, and without the error, it will stay a wild guess.

Comment: are you sitting behind a proxy server ? probably your browser has checked option of automatically detect proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

share you source code and full error logs, but `java.net.UnknownHostException` Exception Thrown to indicate : IP address or host or url could not be determine.

This exception occurring because your internet is not working properly or host URL or ip is not valid. try to ping your host.